# can't boot from usb after motherboard change

Tags: windows-10, boot, motherboard

I recently changed the motherboard of my computer (ASRock JR455 https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/J3455-ITX/index.fr.asp to ASRock B550 https://pg.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B550%20Phantom%20Gaming-ITXax/index.fr.asp).

I want to reinstall Windows 10 on a 128Gb SSD from an USB boot but I get stuck in a perpetual loop where the computer restart before getting to the configuration screen. I have already setup the usb boot as first in the BIOS, changed CSM and UEFI configurations, even switched to another usb port but nothing works.

I still have Windows 10 installed on the SSD but I also get stuck in a loop when trying to boot it. The os crash, I get a blue screen with a KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE error message, then it reboot.

I didn't had this problem before changing motherboard so I think the issue comes from an incompatibility.

I'm seriously stomped and I have no serious clue on what to do, any help will be welcomed, thanks in advance!

Comment: You switched from Intel to AMD. Your original SSD won't boot because all hardware drivers are completely different on AMD. You will have to re-install (upgrade install on top of the existing Windows install may work and keep most of your software and settings, but don't count on it.) As for the USB stick. Try it on another computer first to make sure the stick is working Then try UEFI with SecureBoot disabled or CSM/Legacy mode. Note that in some cases a bios with CSM offers 2 bootmodes (UEFI or CSM) for a stick and you have to manually select the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the fix was simply to strip dow the motherboard, clear the CMOS and then plug it back in. It was probably due to a physical malfunction that was fixed in the process.
I'm now able to boot from my usb stick